# Change react-native-calendar to dark mode

Tags: react-native, expo, velo, react-native-calendars

We are using react-native-calendar from wix.com, we are planning to create a dark mode version but we can not change the agenda background colore. how can i access it ?

[image: 1]

I've found a solution to style the calendar element, the scrollpad, but ot the background of the view where all events are renderd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw an example of the [Agenda component on the repository](https://github.com/wix/react-native-calendars/#agenda) and figure out it has a prop called `theme`. In the `types.ts` file, you can see the theme interface and all properties. Follow a simple example:

```js
<Agenda
  // Agenda theme
  theme={{
    agendaKnobColor: '#768390',
    calendarBackground: '#2d333b',
  }}
/>
```

I created a [snack on Expo](https://snack.expo.dev/@marcelofreires/stackoverflow-questions-75228810?platform=web) for you to see the complete example on the computer with the source code.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the agenda background color by modifying the value of `reservationsBackgroundColor` inside your `theme` object. Here is an example :

```
theme = {
  {
    reservationsBackgroundColor: "#000000",
  }
}
```